# Hide multiple <TR> in table using same condition in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-show, ng-hide

I want to use same ng-show condition in more than 7-8 table rows of a table.
I dont want to repeat the ng-show="same condition" in all 7-8 tr elements.
is there any way i can put the condition in top level?

Below is my code, here sometimes both condition1 and condtion2 are true and sometimes only condition1 is true and some time only condition2 is true
I dont want to repeat conditions everytime.

```
 <table>
     <tr ng-show="condition1" >
       <td>test1 </td><td>some value</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr ng-show="condition1" >
       <td>test2</td><td>some value</td>
   </tr> 
    <tr ng-show="condition2" >
       <td>test3</td><td>some value</td>
   </tr> 
    <tr ng-show="condition2" >
       <td>test4</td><td>some value</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr ng-show="condition2" >
       <td>test5</td><td>some value</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr ng-show="condition2" >
          <td>test6</td><td>some value</td>
   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Depends what you really want to achieve. Can you share your code to make it more clear ?

Comment: You could maybe use `ng-repeat` with a filter to render your 7-8 `tr`s

Comment: Below is my code here sometimes both condition1 and condtion2 are true and sometimes only condition1 is true and some time only condition2 is true    ,`<table>
<tr ng-show="condition1" ><td>test1</td></tr>
<tr ng-show="condition1" ><td>test2</td></tr>
<tr ng-show="condition2" ><td>test3</td></tr>
<tr ng-show="condition2" ><td>test4</td></tr>
<tr ng-show="condition2" ><td>test5</td></tr>
<tr ng-show="condition2" ><td>test6</td></tr>
</table>`

Comment: It would have been possible had your <tr> been generated dynamically using ng-repeat.
I am assuming that is not the case. Correct?

Comment: @Srivathsa, Here sometime you are checking condition1 and sometime you are checking condition2, How the system will know which condition have to check?

Comment: the condition1 always applicable to tr1 and tr 2. and condition2 always applicable to tr 3 to 6.

Comment: @Vipul each tr varies with the content. i cant generate them dynamically. is there any custom tag on which i can add condition and wrap it around tr 3 to 6 and is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way (instead of div try with span as well):

```
    <table>
      <div ng-show="condition1">
         <tr>
           <td>test1 </td><td>some value</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>test2</td><td>some value</td>
       </tr> 
     </div>
     <div ng-show="condition2">
        <tr>
           <td>test3</td><td>some value</td>
       </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>test4</td><td>some value</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>test5</td><td>some value</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
              <td>test6</td><td>some value</td>
       </tr> 
     </div>
    </table>
```

Comment: Unfortunately HTML throws out the `div` or `span` elements in a table

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  <table>
         <tr>
           <td>test1 </td><td>some value</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>test2</td><td>some value</td>
       </tr> 
     <tbody ng-show="condition2">
        <tr>
           <td>test3</td><td>some value</td>
       </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>test4</td><td>some value</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
           <td>test5</td><td>some value</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
              <td>test6</td><td>some value</td>
       </tr> 
     </tbody>
    </table>
```